# How can I import a module by concatenating a variable in the destination route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I am trying to import a module depending on a parameter received in the function, it worked for me when I used Common JS but after I changed to ES Modules I have not been able to do it.

Here is the code that worked for me concatenating the variable with require

```
 fs.readdirSync(PATH_ROUTES).filter((file) => {
    const name = removeExtension(file);
    if (name != 'index') {
        router.use(`/${name}`, require(`./${file}`));
    }
})
```

how i can do it using ES Modules ?

EDIT

this is one of the route files, as you can see I'm importing everything with ESM, since I've fully migrated to ESM.

```
import express from 'express';
import authMiddleware from '../middleware/session.js';
import checkRol from '../middleware/rol.js';
import { validatorGetItem, validatorUpdateItem } from '../validators/users.js';
import { getItems, getItem, updateItem, deleteItem } from '../controllers/users.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", authMiddleware, checkRol(['administrador']), getItems);
router.get("/:id", authMiddleware, checkRol(['administrador']), validatorGetItem, getItem);
router.put("/:id", authMiddleware, checkRol(['administrador']), validatorGetItem, validatorUpdateItem, updateItem);
router.delete("/:id", authMiddleware, checkRol(['administrador']), validatorGetItem, deleteItem);

export default router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a computed filename, you would have to use [dynamic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports)  `import()`, not static `import`.

```
 fs.readdirSync(PATH_ROUTES).forEach(file => {
     const name = removeExtension(file);
     if (name != 'index') {
         router.use(`/${name}`, await import(`./${file}`));
     }
 }
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use ``(await import(`./${file}`)).default`` though

Comment: @Bergi - Yes, that would depend upon whether the files being imported are ALSO being converted to ESM for this purpose - that's what I assumed.

Comment: I get an error **TypeError:  Router.use() requires a Middleware función but got a  promise**

Comment: @Majestic99 - As Bergi commented, you have to make sure your exports from your modules are appropriately usable from an ESM import.  You should either modify your modules to convert them to ESM modules and directly export the middleware function as the `default` export or reference `.default` as Bergi commented if they are still CommonJS modules.  Mixing module types requires careful matching of code on both sides.  If you control the modules being imported in, then convert them to ESM modules and declare their `default` export.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have edited the question, now can you tell me if that is correct?

Comment: @Majestic99 - The `export default router` part looks correct to me.  I don't know about all the other things that file is importing because I don't know what those files export. Is this the code that isn't working?  If so, what is the exact error you get?

Comment: @jfriend00 I already managed to solve it, apparently the files variable stored the name of the files with the extension, so I removed the function that removes the extension in the return and I used it inside the for loop, in this way the import does receive the extension and the path no thank you very much !

Comment: @Majestic99 - Ahhh, I see.  I corrected the code in my answer.  I didn't realize you were using `name` in the `router.use()`.  That part was my mistake.